# ArcGIS Calculate Near by looping through and matching .shp names from two different directories

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I have several thousand shapefiles in one directory (direct1) and several thousand other shapefiles in another directory (direct2).  The files in direct2 will have a match in direct1 and will have the same file name.  I need to do a near analysis by calculating the the nearest point from direct2 to the nearest point in direct1 for files that share the same name.  I found this [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112560/intersecting-two-shapefiles-from-different-folders-based-on-their-name-using-scr) that is pretty much what I want to do, but it is for ArcGIS 9.3.  I am working with ArcGIS 10.3 and looking for some type of updated code and or something that will perform faster!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the linked page and updated for 10.3, the source is pretty much the same. Only difference is that `gp.arcgisscripting` is now simply `arcpy`.

```
import sys,arcpy

InFolder = sys.argv[1]
MatchFolder = sys.argv[2]
OutFolder = sys.argv[3]

arcpy.workspace = InFolder # set the workspace
FeatureClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() # get a list of feature classes

# step through the feature classes
for FC in FeatureClasses:
    MatchFC = MatchFolder + "\\" + FC
    # if the same name is in the match folder
    if arcpy.Exists(MatchFC):
        resultFC = OutFolder + "\\" + FC
        # perform the intersection
        arcpy.Intersect_analysis([FC, MatchFC], resultFC, "ALL", "#", "INPUT")
```

Comment: perfect, thank you!  Didn't realize it was that simple from migrating between 9.3 to 10+!